# Sending Custom Dimension in Event to Google Analytics

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Hello I am trying to attach custom dimension while sending events to Google Analytics using NodeJS.

I am using [universal analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-analytics#event-tracking) npm package.

When I am sending only one custom dimension it is working fine,
but the problem is while setting more than one custom dimensions only the first custom dimension is getting tracked.

```
    visitor.set("cd1", <value>);
    visitor.set("cd2", <value>);
    visitor.event(params).send();
```

Only value of cd1 is reflecting.
Any solution?

Comment: Thats not an official npm package created by google i would contact the developer see if they even support multiple custom dimensions.  https://github.com/peaksandpies/universal-analytics

Comment: thanks, solved the issue bdw.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the required format.
We need to send in this format:

```
params = {
    ec: eventCategoryValue,
    ea: eventActionValue,
    el: eventLabelValue,
    cd1: valueOfCustomDimensionAtIndex1,
    cd2: valueOfCustomDimensionAtIndex2
}
```

It will reflect in GA.